# WPF Set user control dependency properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

Below a piece of my user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Controls.CircularProgressBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Background="Transparent"
             Height="{Binding ControlHeightProperty}"
             Width="{Binding ControlWidthProperty}">

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="progressCirclesColor" Color="#FF2E6187" />
  </UserControl.Resources>

    <Viewbox Width="{Binding ControlWidthProperty}" Height="{Binding ControlHeightProperty}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <!-- other objects -->
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

and its code-behind with my dependency properties:

```
public partial class CircularProgressBar
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ControlHeight", typeof(int), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new UIPropertyMetadata(45));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ControlWidth", typeof(int), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new UIPropertyMetadata(45));

    public int ControlHeight
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ControlHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControlHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public int ControlWidth
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ControlWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControlWidthProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then from my wpf main window:

```
    <ctr:CircularProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Grid.ZIndex="3"                             
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         ControlHeight="100"
                         ControlWidth="100"/>
```

What I am trying to do is set width and height for my user control from my main window. In above example I am trying to set user control height and width to 100 through dependency properties ControlHeight and ControlWidth respectively.

If from my main windows ControlHeight and ControlWidth is not specified, I want user control height and width take as default value of 45.

But above example is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE WORKING**:
As Clemens suggested, I have changed the code into the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Controls.CircularProgressBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Background="Transparent">

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="progressCirclesColor" Color="#FF2E6187" />
  </UserControl.Resources>

    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <!-- other objects -->
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

In code-behind dependency properties ControlHeightProperty and ControlWidthProperty are not needed.

Finally in my wpf window, setting typical height and width properties are enough:

```
    <ctr:CircularProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Grid.ZIndex="3"                             
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Height="100"
                         Width="100"/>
```

Comment: do you get binding errors?

Comment: Besides the actual problem in the question, you know these properties don't make sense, because there are already Width and Height?

Comment: @Clemens I think he only wants to define the size of a control inside the usercontrol. The size of the usercontrol could be anything else.

Comment: @NtFreX Did you see the Width and Height bindings at the UserControl itself? The Viewbox will then fill the entire area of the UserControl, hence the bindings there are pointless.

Comment: @Clemens No I didn't it is possible that it will be added. But you are right. If he wants to set the size of the usercontrol this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @NtFreX My purpose is to set the size of the user control from within the main window where user control is imported and used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to bind to the actual property, not its identifier field, i.e. `ControlWidth` instead of `ControlWidthProperty`.

Besides that, you also have to set a binding source, which in this case is the UserControl instance, referenced either by `RelativeSource Self` at the UserControl level, or `RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl` at any level below.

```
<UserControl Width="{Binding ControlWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ...>

<Viewbox Width="{Binding ControlWidth,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" ...>
```

Note however that none of these bindings really make sense. There is no point in adding a `ControlWidth` property when there already is a `Width`.

At the Viewbox it isn't necessary to bind the Width or Height because the UserControl will already resize it appropriately.

So in fact you don't need any additional property. Your UserControl's XAML should look like shown below, without explicitly setting *any* Width or Height.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Controls.CircularProgressBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Background="Transparent">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="progressCirclesColor" Color="#FF2E6187" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Viewbox>
        <!-- other objects -->
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

When you use that control somewhere in your MainWindow, instead of setting ControlWidth and ControlHeight, just set Width and Height.

Comment: My console showed the `RelativeSource is not in FindAncestor mode` error for a short time but it disapered after I started the application. Strange.

Comment: And I don't suspect you downvoted me? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you see my coment on the question. The only reason I did not answer 2 minutes before you is that I did not want to start my answer with "probably".

Comment: But anyway. I upvoted your answer and the question because they are good and thats how its done on this site. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Clemens, your solution works perfectly! thx. One thing; which is the meaning of setting dependency properties to readonlly?. I have specified them and also removed them and the effect is the same.

Comment: It is not the property that is readonly, but only its identifier field. The field is static and readonly, i.e. defined once at the class level without the possibility to be overwritten.